Examples of high sensitivity of observable behavior to the choice of DFT functional
Most computational materials science studies perform or reference some sort of baseline process for choosing the DFT functional that they will employ to model their system. It is unlikely that a functional reproduces all  properties of a material, but we try to choose one that gets it mostly right. Here I am looking for salient examples of this choice being critical to correctly predict some properties that do not immediately pop out of a relaxed structure. In other words, lattice constants are too easy.
A good answer could be a reference comparing functionals, or a series of references where perhaps an earlier one was acceptable but superceded, or especially where a change in functional gave opposing predictions of some trend or behavior. Ideally less obvious than the phase diagram of water and ices.
The opposite question asking for examples of agreement is here.

Are you asking about solid state calculations in particular, or do gas phase calculations also interest you?

@isolatedmatrix I work with solid state more, so perhaps for me personally it will take a bit more explanation regarding "why this matters" to appreciate gas-phase examples. It is easier for me to imagine examples condensed-phase complexities. But the gas phase (non-periodic calculations) is fair game for the question as I asked it. I hope to see a corpus of diverse answers ("one-topic-per-answer") for the community more than one killer example to rule them all.

Fair enough. The thing I know most about are vibrational frequencies. Are those properties 'non-obvious' enough to qualify?

Does this answer your question? Examples of low sensitivity of observable behavior to the choice of DFT functional

@AndreaPellegrini I'm not sure why you bring up the linked question. The question you linked is also mine, and I set up both questions at the same time to link to each other saying that they are looking for the opposite answers. Could you tell me more about why you suggested it?

@isolatedmatrix sure, and I wonder whether there could be an example of such vibrational frequencies being significant for more crudely observable behavior? Otherwise it can be nontrivial to parse why some quantitative difference in vibrational frequencies matters. Like for water, we kind of know there is sensitivity to functional in the O-H frequency, but how much does it matter for anything that it may be 3500 cm^-1 versus 3600 cm^-1? Hope this helps.

Having two questions for the same topic is superfluous. If you are interested in both, just ask for examples of low or high sensitivity.

I'm okay with having two separate questions here!

Regarding frequencies, I know of a solid-state example that is not just 'quantitative error'. For rutile TiO2, LDA predicts it to be unstable (imaginary modes) while GGA gets it right-ish (all modes real, but there are deviations from expt. for other non-trivial reasons). Dunno if this helps.

@TylerSterling that seems like a nice example

I actually may have said that backwards! LDA predicts stable rutile and GGA unstable. Either way, big difference.
